# What happened to .ajax() between jQuery 1.4.4 and 1.7.2 to make code break?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am in need of moving to jQuery 1.7.2 on a site that is currently using 1.4.4.  I have the below ajax call that works fine in 1.4.4 but is kicking back

> No conversion from text to [object

in 1.7.2.  (I think this has more to do with .parseJSON(), but I am  not sure.)

```
function ajax_update(table_value, key_value, value_value, newkey_value, newvalue_value, debug) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/index.php/ajax/updatepost/",
    data: { 
        table: table_value,
        key: key_value,
        value: value_value,
        newkey: newkey_value,
        newvalue: newvalue_value
    },
    dataType: JSON,
    success: function(data, textStatus){

        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        //both debug and flash going in two different directions
        $("div#flash > p").text(result.message);
        $("div#flash").removeClass().addClass("message").addClass(result.flavor).slideDown(500).delay(1200).slideUp(500);

        if (debug == true) {
            $("div#debugflash > p").text(result.debug);
            $("div#debugflash").removeClass().addClass("message").addClass("information").show();
        }
    },
    error: function(errorObj, textStatus, errorThrown){

        $("div#flash > p").text(errorThrown);
        $("div#flash").removeClass().addClass("message").addClass("error").slideDown(500).delay(1200).slideUp(500);

        if (debug == true) {
            $("div#debugflash > p").text(errorThrown);
            $("div#debugflash").removeClass().addClass("message").addClass("information").show();
        }
    }
});
```

}

The json validates in jsonlint.com, is generated by a php script calling json_encode(array) and looks like this:

```
{"message":"Updated field name with value ALAMO",
"flavor":"success",
"debug":"UPDATE `customers` SET `name` = 'ALAMO' WHERE `cust_id` = 'ALA100'"
```

}

Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 00:00:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Content-Length: 177
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=96
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: where does this error happen?

Comment: I'm getting it back from errorThrown in the error anon function.

Comment: The Ajax does go through, but it returns the error function in 1.7.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with this line

```
dataType: JSON
```

try this instead

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: We are getting to a success function now, but still not getting the actual messages to pass.

Comment: alert(data) is now telling me object Object

Comment: and what if you try to parse it and alert that data?

Comment: @Shane was correct as well.  For some reason, data is not returning the result.  jqXHR.responseText works fine though.  Two problems at the same time is a headache.

Comment: Does the response look right in fiddler(or chrome dev console).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 1.5 rewrote AJAX to be much more extendable.  See http://encosia.com/jquery-1-5s-ajax-rewrite-and-asp-net-services-all-is-well/  Probably your data passed into the success function is already `JSON.parse()`ed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error may have to do with this line:

```
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Try using

```
alert(data);
```

on the previous line to ensure your data variable contains data.

Comment: I'm never getting to the success function to get that to work.  If the error function is returning the data, I don't know how to get at it.

Comment: error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)Function
A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object...

Does the jqXHR object return the data?  I'm dumb and don't know.

Comment: The data should (also) be in jqXHR.responseText

In your error function, can you please insert:

alert(errorObj.status)

just at the top